# Java Jackson - how to parse list of objects with an arbatrary identifier tag

Tags: java, jackson, pojo

I have a JSON record that looks like this:

```
    {"ActionRecord": {
        "101": {
            "Desc": "string 1",
            "Done": 1,
            "MaxTimes": 2,
            "Point": 30,
            "Times": 4
        },
        "102": {
            "Desc": "string 2",
            "Done": 1,
            "MaxTimes": 3,
            "Point": 15,
            "Times": 13
        },
        "103": {
            "Desc": "string 3.",
            "Done": 1,
            "MaxTimes": 5,
            "Point": 15,
            "Times": 24
        }, ... }
```

I can get Jackson to parse this if i create a hacky intermediate class that contains a field for each number, and then use something like this in the class:

```
    @JsonProperty( value = "101" )
    public MyClass hundred_one;
    @JsonProperty( value = "102" )
    public MyClass hundred_two;
    @JsonProperty( value = "103" )
    public MyClass hundred_three;
```

But I have to type out all the expected values, so it would be much easier to be able to use an array list of objects, and insert the numeric id into the POJO with Jackson's mapper.

Is there a way have Jackson automatically map it into a class like this? :

```
public enum ActionRecord { 

Something   ( "101" ),
SomethingElse( "102" ),
AnotherSomething ( "103" ),
;    
String _id;    
EK_DailyTaskInfo_ActionRecord( String id )
{
   _id = id;
}    
public String getId()
{
   return _id;
}        
public String  Desc;     // "some string.",
public boolean Done;     // 1,
public int     Times;    // 4
public int     MaxTimes; // 2,
public int     Point;    // 30,
}
```

It does not have to be an enum this was just something I was trying before I gave up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson can decode it into a `Map<String, Record>` for you, e.g.

```
public class Record {
public String  Desc;     // "some string.",
public boolean Done;     // 1,
public int     Times;    // 4
public int     MaxTimes; // 2,
public int     Point;    // 30,
}

public class ActionRecords {
public Map<String, Record> ActionRecord
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well I am using `GSON` library in shown example, Android has it's own api to handle the `JSON` where a iterator is very useful, code is also available on [github](https://github.com/pankajnimgade/JavaCoding_tutorials/blob/master/src/stack/overflow/test/first/ReadJsonOne.java)

What i want to propose is that you should read all the keys with respect to it's key's and get the `JsonObject` from there, you you have a JsonList which is not an array this is what you can do

```
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement element = parser.parse(result); // result is your json data
        JsonObject obj = element.getAsJsonObject();

        System.out.println(obj.toString());

        JsonObject jsonObject = obj.getAsJsonObject("ActionRecord"); // this will get the JsonObject with the key ActionRecord

        System.out.println(jsonObject);

        Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> stringSet = jsonObject.entrySet(); // this will map all the JsonObject with it's keys

        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> key :stringSet) {
            System.out.println(jsonObject.getAsJsonObject(key.getKey()).toString());
        }
```

Once you have the key with it's corresponding `JSONObject`, you can create populate your own type for that object.

well this is for `Gson`, you might want to look for equivalent of this in `Jackson`

```
output
{"Desc":"string 1","Done":1,"MaxTimes":2,"Point":30,"Times":4}
{"Desc":"string 2","Done":1,"MaxTimes":3,"Point":15,"Times":13}
{"Desc":"string 3.","Done":1,"MaxTimes":5,"Point":15,"Times":24}
```